# Нужно ли тире в предложении "Какие модели рекомендуются, а какие (-) нет?"

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Какое правило в данном случае действует?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Какие модели рекомендУются, а какие нЕт?**

Это предложение лучше представить в виде двух фраз без параллельной интонации и паузы, тогда тире на месте пропуска не ставится. Такое решение подходит для нераспространенного предложения простой и понятной  конструкции при пропуске одного слова.

Но постановка тире тоже не является ошибкой, в этом случае логически подчеркивается выбор (ударение делается на местоимениях *какие*).

**Правило Розенталя**  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93#pp93

2. Тире ставится в неполных предложениях при параллелизме конструкций (предложений или частей предложения). При отсутствии паузы в месте пропуска члена предложения тире не ставится:

**Пояснение**

Таким образом,  в неполных предложениях тире ставится не всегда. Мы ставим тире при наличии паузы (или   параллельной интонации и паузы)  и не ставим при их отсутствии. Чаще тире используется, когда пропущенная часть предложения достаточно объёмная и  ее желательно заменить паузой.

**Примеры:**

(1) Морским пехотинцам перед началом встречи были даны строгие указания по поводу того, какие вопросы мОжно задавать, а какие нЕт (= нельзя). Здесь пропуск  одного слова, всё понятно и без тире.

(2) Поэтому важно тщательно изучить эти расходы и понять, **какИе из них необходИмы, а какие — нЕт** (= из них не являются необходимыми).

Шукшин спросил меня: «А вот как вы думаете, ведь должны же быть такие люди, которые объясняют нашему не очень образованному руководству, какие **фильмы нАдо выпускать на экран**, а какие ― нЕт?

Пропущена значительная часть предложения (не одно слово), поэтому лучше поставить тире.

Answer (score 2):

В качестве неполного ответа приведу несколько относящихся к вопросу цитат из авторитетных источников:

> ...Какие звенья структурной схемы предложений и словосочетаний
>   реализованы, **а какие нет**. (Н. М. Шанский, "Современный русский язык:
>   Синтаксис, пунктуация")
>
> При чтении вслух ученик замечает, какие запятые он читает, **а какие
>   нет**... (Хрестоматия по методике русского языка)
>
> Какие из них годились бы для данного места (помимо размера), **а какие
>   нет**? (А.М.Пешковский, "Наш язык")
>
> ...Укажите, какие задания выполнены, **а какие нет**. (Русский язык в
>   школе)

В заслуживающих доверия источниках мне ни разу не попалось тире.

Дополнение: плохо искал. См. ответ **Серж**.

Answer (score 2):

В приведенном вами примере, тире действительно заменяет отрицаемую часть предшествующей фразы: "а какие модели рекомендуются". Однако оно не является здесь обязательным.

> См. Большой толковый словарь под редакцией Кузнецова.

Нет//  Вместо сказ. с отриц., а также вместо словосоч. или целого предл. с отриц., когда они противопоставляются предыдущему. **Возник спор: одни утверждали, что нужно строить дорогу, другие - что нет**

Это неполное предложение. В таких предложениях  тире употребляется для обозначения паузы и интонационного подчеркивания. При отсутствии паузы и интонационного подчеркивания тире не ставится.

См. также другие примеры.

**Оставлю читателю решать вопросы о том, какие из этих целей были достигнуты, а какие ― нет.** [И. Г. Милославский. Говорим правильно по смыслу или по форме? (2013)]

**Именно автор программы определяет, какие критерии ЭВМ должна посчитать как совпадение, а какие ― нет.** [Валентин Зелинский. Виражи криминальной экспертизы // «Криминальный отдел», 2010]

**Поэтому важно тщательно изучить эти расходы и понять, какие из них необходимы, а какие — нет.** [Антон Попов, Марк Херд. «Сегодня мы самодостаточны» (2008.02.04)

Answer (score 1):

В вашем примере тире перед словом "нет" заменяет отрицаемую часть предшествующей фразы: "а какие модели рекомендуются".